# SElinux: How Context type is used to approve or prevent access?

Tags: selinux

I am new to SElinux and would like your help answering this :

how can we check if the context type of a program meets the SElinux context type of a file and hence prevent denials.

for example **shadow_t** of the **/etc/shadow** file matched with the **chkpwd_t** of **/usr/sbin/unix_chkpwd** program.

Many thanks
Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify allowed interactions between contexts. Every interaction that is not explicitly allowed is forbidden in SELinux.

If you want to allow `/usr/sbin/unix_chkpwd` to read `/etc/shadow` then there should be a policy that explicitly allows it:

```
allow chkpwd_t shadow_t:file getattr open read ioctl lock map;
```

You can search for existing policies with `sesearch`.

```sh
sesearch --allow --source chkpwd_t --target shadow_t --class file
```